# Shopify settings selector with dynamic options

Tags: shopify, liquid

Under one of my section's settings, I have a country block where admins can add countries in.

And below that I have a locations block where admins can add locations. In there there is a text option to add addresses and a selector option where I hope to have a dropdown selector which can dynamically update its options based on the first country settings.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Please provide reference code to the issue.

Comment: Shopify options and settings can't be updated dynamically at this point